# Powerpoint & VBA New slide if table bottom exceeds the bottom of the slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So i have been struggling with this for the past few days, i have this powerpoint 2007 presentation that i fill with information from a button in a from in a access file using VBA.

And in the first slide (and only by now) i have a table that will receive part of the information, however i can't make the table content break to another slide if the table exceeds the bottom of the slide, it just goes out of range.

I have the method to create a the new slide, and that works fine. But i can't seem to find an example that could get me started.

I think i should be something like check the table bottom exceeds slide bottom if it does create a new slide, cut the overlap cells and paste them in the new slide?

Thanks in Advance.

The code example:

```
    ' Open PowerPoint
    Dim pptobj As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim Presentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oSl as Slide

    Set pptobj = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set pptobj = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    pptobj.Activate
    Set Presentation = pptobj.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\some.pptx")
    pptobj.Visible = True
    pptobj.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized

    If ((Len(Forms!Some!Name> 0) Then
        pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableNome").Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!Name))
    End If

      Set oSl = pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    With oSl
        .Shapes("TableCategory").Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!CVLong!TxtCategory))
        .Shapes("TableEmail").Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!TxtEmail))
        .Shapes("TableData").Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!TxtTlf))
        .Shapes("TableData").Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!TxtCell))
    End With

    Dim oSh as Shape
    Dim overhang        

    Set oSh = pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddTable(1, 3, 50, 100, 493)

        'One
    If ((Len(Forms!Some!One)) > 0) Then
        pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(1, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!One)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "One"
    End If

'Two

    If (Len(Forms!Some!Two> 0) Then
        pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(5, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!Two)) & vbNewLine
        pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(5, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Two"
     End If

'Three
    If (Len(Forms!Some!Three) > 0) Then
                pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(4, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!Three)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
                pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(4, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Three"
    End If


'Add Slide
    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1

     Set Sld = pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)

    For Each Sld In pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides

        If x >= 2 Then
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Text Placeholder 15").Copy
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes.Paste
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes("Text Placeholder 15").ZOrder msoSendToBack
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes("Text Placeholder 15").Height = 810
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes("Text Placeholder 15").Top = 19
        End If
    x = x + 1
    Next

End If

  'Put table top border
Dim n As Integer
Dim r As Integer
n = 3
r = 1

While r <= n
        If Len(pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(r, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) > 0 Then
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(r, 3).Borders(ppBorderTop).Visible = msoTrue
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Cell(r, 3).Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
        Else
            pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TableInfo").Table.Rows(r).Delete
            n = n - 1
            r = r - 1
        End If
        r = r + 1
Wend

'Add Photo
    pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="\\someplace\" & [Id] & ".jpg", linktofile:=mostrue, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=52, Top:=115).Select

    With pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Picture 7")
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 85
        .Left = 38
        .Top = 80
    End With

'add footer
    Dim page As Integer
    page = 1
    Dim s As Slide

     For Each s In pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides
         On Error Resume Next
         Set oSh = s.HeadersFooters.Footer
             If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                 Call s.Master.Shapes.AddPlaceholder(ppPlaceholderFooter, 219, 805, 342, 19)
             End If
        On Error GoTo 0
            s.HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = msoTrue
            s.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = (CStr(Forms!Some!Name)) & " - Page " & page & " of " & pptobj.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            page = page + 1
    Next
```

Comment: What does this mean: " that i fill with information from **a button in a from in a** access file using VBA."? Could you show the code you have so far to get the data and create the table - and what you have tried to determine that the table is too big?

Comment: I suspect it'd be easier to create a table on the first slide and add data a row at a time, checking .Top + .Height of the table shape after each row has been added. If that value is within a safety margin of the slide's height, add a new slide, add a table to it and continue adding your data to the new table.

Comment: A couple of other resources for you from the PPT FAQ site I maintain:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00892_Using_Excel_and_Access_data_in_PowerPoint_Tables_-by_Brian_Reilly_and_Naresh_Nichani-.htm and http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00795_Controlling_Office_Applications_from_PowerPoint_-by_Naresh_Nichani_and_Brian_Reilly-.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - had you seen my answer when you posted your first comment? It's quite similar...

Comment: First of all, thank you soo much, your approach, seems to be the right way to ho however i'm trying to use the code that @Floris wrote but it gives me a error when setting the oSh variable, it gives the Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. the code has been added to the orignal post, it's not yeat finish. Once again thanks

Comment: What happens if you change the declaration of the variable to `Dim oSl` ? Leave off the `As Shape` ?

Comment: @Floris: yes, I saw your answer first, but didnt' feel it really solved the problem completely.  The example code I pointed to on the PPTFAQ site pulls data from Access and builds a table across multiple slides as needed; IOW, it almost directly answers Nelson's problem.  One interesting thing: your code doesn't throw any errors here as it did for Nelson. I'm using PPT 2010, in case that matters.

Comment: floris, i have not been able to put the solution to work as i wish i'm using both your indications to do so, just let me finish, and i will see wich answer is more usefull, never the less, both of you have helped me very much. thank you.

btw, formating a table in vba is quite hard (setting borders, no background, font color and size, etc..). I'm using ppt 2007.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I agree your link adds more information - but I didn't think that was the part OP was struggling with. And yes, Powerpoint has an annoying habit of changing the object model from one version to the next - I noticed big changes from 2003 to 2010, with objects that were formerly "shapes" becoming "placeholders" of type "shape", etc. So I'm not too surprised that the `AddTable()` doesn't return a `Shape` for Nelson, but something else. Nelson - if you have a correctly formatted table example in your presentation, you might try to do a copy - paste special - formats.

Comment: that is a good ideia floris, but that's the table i have to delete now because it's the one that i was going to cut if it became to big to the silde, since i'm creating a new one, that is of no use. unless i cut it and then paste it it just one row and then add new rows as needed. i'll give it a try

Comment: First create the new tables, copy/paste the formats, then delete the table you no longer need... You could even "hide" it on a slide in the template that is not used in the presentation- that way it is available when you need it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet may give you some inspiration.  Right now it just determines that the table is too large and gives you a message. Without more information about the type of data and how you obtained it, it's hard to give an answer to the second part of the problem. Most likely you would create a table, add one row at a time and check the size of the table; when the table gets too large (or within a certain distance from the bottom) you create a new slide and continue the process. That is probably better than creating a table that's too large, then trying to figure out where to cut it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub createTable()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim overhang

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTable(28, 3)

overhang = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - (oSh.Height + oSh.Top)

If overhang > 0 Then
  MsgBox "the table fits"
Else
  MsgBox "the table is too big!"
End If

End Sub
```